# Find highest and lowest value by date

Tags: php, arrays, date

I am trying to split an array base upon its value, I have tried using min and max but cannot figure out how to group it by the value of each key

My array

```
Array
    (
        [2018-10-18] => 5
        [2018-10-19] => 5
        [2018-10-20] => 5
        [2018-10-21] => 5
        [2018-10-22] => 5
        [2018-10-23] => 5
        [2018-10-24] => 5
        [2018-10-25] => 5
        [2018-10-26] => 5
        [2018-10-27] => 5
        [2018-10-28] => 4
        [2018-10-29] => 4
        [2018-10-30] => 4
        [2018-10-31] => 4
        [2018-11-01] => 4
        [2018-11-02] => 4
        [2018-11-03] => 4
    )
```

Desired result

```
Array
(
  [0] => array(
    'start' => '2018-10-18',
     'end' => '2018-10-27',
     'value' => 5
  ),
  [1] => array(
    'start' => '2018-10-28',
     'end' => '2018-11-03',
     'value' => 4
  )

)
```

Comment: What did you tried?

Comment: Show us at least one of your attempts

Comment: @MickaelLeger "I have tried using min and max" suggests to me the OP tried a solution with either `array_min` or a `min` like function.

Comment: Exactly tried using with min and max which gives lowest and highest date but not  by the value

Comment: lets see the code of what you tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The brute-force way is to first rotate your array to group-by value, then to calculate on those groups:

```
// Start with your source data in $array, then:
// Rotate the array so it's keyed by value. I think you were getting
// stuck on this step. The result is an array of value => array (dates)
$rotate = [];                                                                    
foreach ($array as $date => $value) {                                            
    $rotate[$value][] = $date;                                                   
}

// Now we'll just calculate the values we want                                                                            
$group = [];                                                                     
foreach ($rotate as $value => $dates) {                                          
    $group[] = [ 'start' => min($dates), 'end' => max($dates), 'value' => $value ];
}
```

[See it online at 3v4l.org.](https://3v4l.org/N6E6D)

Answer (score 0):

You can loop only unique values and use array_intersect to find where these values are.

```
foreach(array_unique($arr) as $v){
    $temp = array_keys(array_intersect($arr, [$v]));
    $new[] = ['start' => current($temp), 
              'end'   => end($temp),
              'value' => $v];
}
var_dump($new);
```

Output of this:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["start"]=>
    string(10) "2018-10-18"
    ["end"]=>
    string(10) "2018-10-27"
    ["value"]=>
    int(5)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["start"]=>
    string(10) "2018-10-28"
    ["end"]=>
    string(10) "2018-11-03"
    ["value"]=>
    int(4)
  }
}
```

https://3v4l.org/YO0cp